# Access fields of a MessageEvent

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, angular6

I have an Angular 6 frontend application that communicates via Websocket with my backend.

When I send a login request my backend returns a JSON object

```
{"type":"LoggedIn","value":{"email":"1@1.de","id":9,"name":"1"}}
```

I try now to read the fields there but I see no method that allows me to do that.

So far I can display the whole backend message with that function:

```
  this.socketService.receiveEvents('LoggedIn').subscribe((message: MessageEvent) => {
      console.log('message: ' + message.data);
    });
```

receiveEvents (principle of completeness):

```
 /**
   * TODO: Implement a paramemter that allows this method to return an Observable
   * TODO: with a filter for relevant events for the calling functions
   * @returns {Observable<Object>}
   */
  receiveEvents(relevantEvent): Observable<Object> {
    return this._subject.asObservable().pipe(filter((event: Event) => event != null));
  }
```

How could I display for example only the field "type" or "value" ?

I already tried to iterate over it with a for loop, but I only receive single letters.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the output of the console log?

Comment: {"type":"LoggedIn","value":{"email":"1@1.de","id":9,"name":"1"}}

Comment: so if you did this: `(<any>message.data).type` what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do kinda this:

```
interface BackendResponse {

  type: string;
  value: string[];
}

this.socketService.receiveEvents('LoggedIn').subscribe((message: MessageEvent) => {
  const obj: BackendResponse = JSON.parse(message.data);
  console.log(obj.type);
});
```

This should bring you on the right path =)